# How to set Chef Vault variable in recipe

Tags: ruby, ldap, chef-infra

Below is the command used to create the vault

```
knife vault create ldapuser user1 -A "admin,chef1.example.com" -J password.json -M client
```

Below is the command that shows content of the vault

```
knife vault show ldapuser user1
id:       user1
password: secretp@ssword
username: james
```

Below is my recipe which includes the following at the very top

```
chef_gem 'chef-vault' do
  compile_time true if respond_to?(:compile_time)
  action :install
end

require 'chef-vault'

item = ChefVault::Item.load("ldapuser","user1")

execute 'setup ldap' do
 command '/opt/ldap/bin/setup --hostname localhost --port 389 --bindDN cn="Directory Manager" --bindPassword item[password] --ldapport 389 --baseDN "dc=example,dc=com" --addBaseEntry --doNotStart --acceptLicense`
end

execute 'run ldap' do
 command '/opt/ldap/bin/ldapmodify --hostname localhost --port 389 --bindDN cn="Directory Manager" --bindPassword item[password] --filename /opt/ldap.ldif
end
```

Unfortunately once setup is complete and i try to log into my ldap server, i get an invalid credentials error message.

I assume it has to do with how the variable for the bindPassword is defined in the execute block. I even tried logging in using item['password'] and that didnt work. However when i hard code the password (instead of using the vault) into my recipe, i am able to login without any issues.

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution that works. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation in Ruby looks like this: `"something #{item['key']} else"`.

Important bits: use double quotes not single, put `#{}` around the expression, and make sure you correctly format the expression inside the `#{}`.

Comment: Your solution is exactly what i was looking for. This did it for me  `--rootUserPassword #{item['password']}`. Only issue i have  now is that the password includes a semi colon special character which is breaking the chef run. I am not sure if i need to escape the special character in the vault itself or if i can get away with something like so `--rootUserPassword #{item["'password'"]}`

Comment: That would only show up if there was actually a semicolon in the data you put in the bag item. Fortunately Ruby has a helper for this: `Shellwords.escape(item['password'])` will escape things for Bash automatically. You might need to add `require 'shellwords' to the top of the file too.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I'm populating a auth.properties and a pem file from secrets from the chef-vault.
Full YouTube Demo Here: [How to Create and use Chef-Vault](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hjZpGypu2E)

Default.rb recipe

```
chef_gem 'chef-vault' do
  compile_time true if respond_to?(:compile_time)
end

require 'chef-vault'
secrets = ChefVault::Item.load("vault_demo", "dev_secrets" )

directory "/opt/your_project" do
  action :create
end

template '/opt/your_project/auth.properties' do
  source "auth.properties.erb"
  variables({
    sql_password: secrets['sql_password'],
    application_password: secrets['application_password']
  })
  action :create
end

template '/opt/your_project/server.pem' do
  source "server.pem.erb"
  variables({
    ssl_cert: Base64.decode64(secrets['ssl_cert'])
  })
  action :create
end
```

Here are the templates:

auth.properties.erb

```
ssl_password:<%= @sql_password %>
application_password:<%= @application_password %>
```

server.pem.erb

```
<%= @ssl_cert %>
```

Note that the pem file is being base64 decoded in the recipe because it has to be encoded to store in the vault